# How to delay next(value) on subject?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, rxjs5, subject

My AlertService has 
`private subject = new Subject<Alert>();`.
I want to autocratically clear alert after 5 seconds. I can do it with using `setTimeout()` like this:

```
autoClear(alertId?: string) {
   setTimeout(
      () => this.subject.next(new Alert({alertId})),
   5000);
  }
```

I tried to do that more elegant and I created this code:

```
autoClear(alertId?: string) {
    const delay = new Observable(x => {
      x.next();
    }).delay(5000).subscribe(() => {
      this.subject.next(new Alert({alertId}));
      delay.unsubscribe();
    });
  }
```

Both of example **works** but it doesn't look like a proper way of using RxJS. How can I improve it?

Comment: I think you are done with the best. Go with any one of the your way. both are good. But I am not sure which one is best for performance.

Comment: I don't understand - you are emitting a new alert after 5 seconds - how is this same as clearing alerts?

Comment: @WandMaker https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2-5-alerts?file=app%2F_services%2Falert.service.ts

Answer (score 3):

```
new Observable(x => {
  x.next();
}).delay(5000);
```

is the correct way. The new way with the pipeables operators is

```
new Observable(x => {
  x.next();
}).pipe(delay(5000));
```

Comment: don't forget to `.subscribe()`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a more readable version could be using `timer` and `take(2)` like this:

```
function autoClear(alertId: any) {
  timer(0, 1000)
    .pipe(
      take(2),
    )
    .subscribe(i => i === 0
      ? subject.next(`start: ${alertId}`)
      : subject.next('stop')
    );
}
```

With `take(2)` you make it obvious that there're only two states. The two `subject.next()` calls are right next to each other so you can quickly see what you're sending in `next()` later.

See live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-8ez3af?file=index.ts